# How to send a json string as an input parameter to a POST request in android

Tags: java

and facing a problem in sending the JSON string to a POST request.

This is my URL: http://172.25.183.183:8080/JIRAservice/rest/runquery

Key : query

Value:

```
{ "jql": "project=<projectkey>",
  "startAt": 0, 
  "maxResults": 100,
  "fields": [
     "summary",
     "customfield_10006",
     "status",
     "description"
   ]
}
```

Where `<projectkey>` is the value stored in the shared preferences please help

this is my code

```
 try{
            TextView op=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.resp); 
            URL url=new URL("http://172.25.183.183:8080/JIRAservice/rest/runquery");
            HttpsURLConnection conn=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            String projectKey=Home.savedid;

           JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    jsonParam.put("query", "             "{ \"jql\": \"project=" + projectKey + "\", \"startAt\": 0, \"maxResults\": 100, \"fields\": [\"summary\",\"customfield_10006\", \"status\", \"description\"] }"");

how to send the parameters??


            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream dbstrm=new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dbstrm.flush();
            dbstrm.close();

            int respnse=conn.getResponseCode();
            String output="Request URl"+url;
            output+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
            output+=System.getProperty("line.separator")+"Response Code"+respnse;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line= "";
            StringBuilder respop=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                respop.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            output +=System.getProperty("line.separator")+respop.toString();
            op.setText(output);


        }catch(MalformedURLException ae){
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What part of the code do you have already?

Comment: This depends very much on the api on the server side...  you can build json objects, and execute async tasks to post your data...  but the method to do it is really down to your server

Comment: The key and the value should be sent simultaneously

Comment: I am able to establish the connection but stuck near sending the input parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try{

            URL url=new URL("http://172.25.183.183:8080/JIRAservice/rest/runquery");
            HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            String projectKey=Home.savedid;
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query"," { \"jql\": \"project=" + projectKey + "\", \"startAt\": 0, \"maxResults\": 100, \"fields\": [\"summary\",\"customfield_10006\", \"status\", \"description\"] }"));
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            conn.connect();

            int respnse=conn.getResponseCode();
            String output="Request URl"+url;
            output+=System.getProperty("line.separator");
            output+=System.getProperty("line.separator")+"Response Code"+respnse;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line= "";
            StringBuilder respop=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                respop.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            output +=System.getProperty("line.separator")+"IssueList from API"+respop.toString();
            System.out.println("IssueList"+ output);
            String respfield=resp(respop.toString());
            System.out.println(" response"+ respfield);




        }catch(MalformedURLException ae){
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**getQuery() method**

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params)
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```